# How to setup robot framework project for docker parallel testing

Tags: docker, pycharm, robotframework

Hi I am really new to robot framework and docker so please bear with me.
I have test cases written in robot framework using PyCharm which are executing fine.
I also have grid up and running which contains one firefox and one chrome browser.
I want to run my testcases in parallel on that grid. Every test case on a separate browser side by side. I need help on what changes to make in my project and how to execute them on docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests run on Grid browsers if we pass the following params to Open Browser keyword:

```
Open Browser ${URL}  ${Browser}  ${NONE}  http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying Selenoid, I use it for paralleled cross-browser run on Docker: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/

Comment: Can you refer me to some guide which runs all my testcases in parallel on selenoid.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea setup CI with Robot Framework, you can get some information to build it:

https://github.com/dylanops/docker-robot-framework